# Why do I keep getting this type error?(python)

Tags: python, types

I understand this may be basic but I have a task of creating two functions for finding mean and median values and them implementing them into a program which will ask for an input of a sequence of numbers. I made both functions separately and tested them, both worked fine I've now put them into the same program and just keep getting a type error telling me to look back at my mean_average(). Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to go about fixing it. I don't see why the mean function worked perfectly using lists before but now it says the oprand type won't work with 'int' and 'list'.

```
values = []
loopy = 0


#Median
def median_average(*args):
    loop = 0
    num_order = sorted(args)
    length = len(args)
    half_length = int((length/2)-1)
    half_length_1 = int((length/2))
    if length % 2 == 0:
        even_averagenf = (num_order[half_length]+num_order[half_length_1])/2
        even_average = float(even_averagenf)
        loop = 1

    if length % 2 != 0:
        odd_average = (num_order[int(half_length_1)])
        loop = 2

    if loop == 2:
        return odd_average

    if loop == 1:
        return even_average

#Mean
def mean_average(*args):
    mean = sum(args)/len(args))
    return mean



while loopy < 1:
    user_v = (input("Please enter your sequence of numbers, stop by typing 'end':"))

    if user_v == "end":
        print("The median value of your sequence is:", median_average(values))
        print("The mean value of your sequence is:", mean_average(values))      
        loopy = 1

    else:
        values.append(int(user_v))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please provide the exact text of the error you're getting.

Comment: `mean = sum(args)/len(args))` doesn't that throw a syntax error?

Comment: Put `print(args)` at the top of `mean_average` and you'll see the problem. The way you've written it, `args` is `[[1,2,3]]`.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't unpack the arguments in your functions

```
def median_average(*args)
def mean_average(*args)
```

You want to handle the actual list itself

```
def median_average(args)
def mean_average(args)
```

This way `args` is the list of values, so you can call `sum` and `len` on it.